# How to access nested json objects without json_decoding the collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following data structure:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "customer_id": "11",
      "customer_name": "Vic",
      "cheque_withdraw": {
         "id": 2,
         "request_date", "2019-03-30"
      }
   }
]
```

I have gotten this data from multiple tables through the following code;

```
$paginator = Cheque::with(['chequeWithdraw' => function($query){
        $query->where('withdraw_status' , 'withdrawn');
    }])
    ->paginate(5);
```

How do I access the nested json object request_date without having to convert my collection to an associative array? The reason why I do not want to convert the collection to an associative array is because I am having challenges paginating the data that has been json decoded.
I am currently trying to access the request_date in my blade file this way;

```
@foreach($paginator as $cheque)
   {{ $cheque->cheque_withdraw->request_date }}
@endforeach
```

However, I am getting the following error;

```
Trying to get property 'request_date' of non-object
```

Comment: If you try to  `print_r($cheque);` and `die();` inside your foreach

What do you get?

Comment: @pr1nc3 I am getting objects of the two models I used. The Cheque model and ChequeWithdraw model. The result is too long else I would have pasted it here for you to have a look

Comment: Then can you show me the code that you return the data to the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you have `chequeWithdraw` and not `cheque_withdraw`

```
@foreach($paginator as $cheque)
   {{ $cheque->chequeWithdraw->request_date  ?? 'NA'}}
@endforeach
```

You might be trying to convert laravel collection to json or array. laravel convert  `camel case` to `snake case` . So you were getting it for json not for laravel template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works wonderfully. Kindly explain to me why the object is chequeWithdraw and not cheque_withdraw as it is in the json?

Comment: @gerry: you might be trying to convert laravel collection to json or array. laravel convert  `camel case` to `snake case` . So you were getting it for json not for laravel template.